# Unity3d: Handle WebGL JavaScript Callback

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following javascript plugin located here: `Plugins/WebGL/GameSmartJs.jslib`

```
var GameSmartJs = {
    PurchaseItem: function (itemName, callback) {
        gamesmart.store.purchase(Pointer_stringify(itemName), function (result) {
            callback({ purchased: result.purchased });
        });
    }
}
```

When this is called it opens a modal on the webpage which has 2 buttons, one to confirm the purchase and one to decline the purchase.

The code for the purchase looks somewhat like this (This is on the website in the browser):

```
purchase: function (itemName, callback) {
    parent.gs.store.showItemPurchase(itemName, getPlayToken()).then(function (result) {
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(result);
        }
    }).catch(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

When this completes (one of the two buttons were pressed in the modal) the callback from the plugin should run.

What I am not sure of is how to get the result of the callback to get mapped to `Action<StorePurchaseResponse>`

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class StorePurchaseResponse {

    public bool purchased;

}
```

Here is how I am initiating the JavaScript:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class GameSmartStore : GameSmart {

    // Displays a item purchase modal
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern string PurchaseItem(string itemName, Action<StorePurchaseResponse> onComplete);

    public void Purchase(string itemName, Action<StorePurchaseResponse> onComplete = null){
        PurchaseItem(itemName, onComplete);
    }

}
```

---

### Edit

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-jslib-2-way-communication.323629/#post-2100593

Based on that link, I have come up with this:

```
var GameSmartJs = {
    $GameSmartStore: {},
    PurchaseItem: function (itemName, obj) {
        gamesmart.store.purchase(Pointer_stringify(itemName), function (result) {
            GameSmartStore.PurchaseCallback = obj(result.purchased);
            Runtime.dynCall('v', obj, 0);
        });
    }
};

autoAddDeps(GameSmartJs, '$GameSmartStore');
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, GameSmartJs);
```

and this for the C# (however I am not sure if it works).

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern string PurchaseItem(string itemName, Action<bool> onComplete);

    public void Purchase(string itemName, Action<bool> onComplete = null){
        if(purchaseStarted){ return; }

        PurchaseItem(itemName, (purchased) => {
            onComplete(purchased);
        });

    }
```

Comment: I'm just guessing but most online transactions happen with JSON so you'd use some library like MiniJSON or DeJson or Json.net to convert the data from Json back into classes or into dictionaries that you then use to get the data.

Comment: I found this: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/c-jslib-2-way-communication.323629/#post-2100593 but I am not sure how I would pass a true/false value back